# How to get graphql query with filter

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am unable to get a query out of my graphql and I wonder why the following codes fail me .

while

```
query
{
  allCockpitHello{
    edges{
      node{
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

gives me the out put of

```
{
  "data": {
    "allCockpitHello": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "Cockpit__Hello__5c65992264343100000001c3"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "Cockpit__Hello__5c90b32864343100000001ab"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot get any query by

```
query
{
  allCockpitHello{
    edges{
      node ( id :"Cockpit__Hello__5c90b32864343100000001ab"){
        Name{
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to filter out the names by ID so that my out put gives me only one result.

Comment: Are you using prisma in backend? Because graphQL doesn't support filtering, sorting and other stuff by default. You have to implement it yourself.

Comment: I am using Cockpit JS as backend.

Comment: So you'll have to implement filtering yourself with a custom query/mutation resolver.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know a specific node ID, a common convention (from [Relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/objectidentification.htm)) is for there to be a *top-level* query named `node` that returns its object.  (You can "jump" directly to the object, you don't have to run the whole query to get there.)  The one catch is that you have to know the object's type as well.

```graphql
query GetHello($id: ID!) {
  node(id: $id) {
    ... on Hello {
      name {
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't know the object type from the schema, there is [a built-in `__typename` field on all objects](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Type-Name-Introspection) that can return it.

```graphql
query { allCockpitHello { edges {
  node {
    __typename
    id
  }
} } }
```

As @HemantParashar noted in a comment, GraphQL is much more of an API layer than a query language *per se*.  A service can define any parameters it wants to on any fields, but there aren't built-in options for things like filtering and sorting.  There is no universal GraphQL way to say "find only child nodes that have this name".